# Accessing my school admin's username & password to un-install the securly certificate on MacBook Air

Tags: macbook-pro, security, hacking

Well, I've been having a lot of issues with Securly recently, as it's been blocking me from every site that I wanted to go on, like pixilart.com. Anyway, it just says that **"it's not allowed by the school restrictions".** The reason for pixilart.com to be blocked is because **"it's a social media platform".** However, *it's a social media platform for all ages.* Plus, *it blocks* ***ALL VPNs,*** *but it doesn't explain why it was blocked.* Anyway, it blocking all free non-download VPNs so that *no one can get by without being noticed by Securly.*

How can I overcome the restrictions or un-install Securly?

Comment: If the laptop belongs to the school, then it's up to them how they let you use it.

Comment: Ok then. I do agree with this, but this may be off topic. Even though you're saying that they control how I can use it, I need to just remove the Securly certificate and store the password just in case they re-install the Securly extension. Thank you for this information, as I will not report this.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the asker wants to remove restrictions on a device they don't own.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically you can't overcome the restrictions set by Securly (or any other such tool). You should approach the school administration if

- you are blocked from doing work mandated by the school
- this is your personal device and you want to have the restrictions removed

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I think that I am just blocked from removing the extension unless I have the admin's credentials, but I don't currently have it, so I have to wait until then, but I'm fine with that.

Answer (score 6):

I want to add this in here as a word of caution.

As someone who has written acceptable use policies for educational establishments, there are "boiler plate" provisions (meaning pretty standard across the entire industry) that you're going to find that you've agreed to even if you don't remember agreeing to them:

- **Use of an identity/password other than the user's own is prohibited.**
- Any use of telecommunication services or networks for illegal,  inappropriate...shall be prohibited.  Illegal  activities shall be  defined as a violation of local, state, and/or federal laws.  Inappropriate use shall be defined as a violation of the intended use
- **Users shall not intentionally** spread computer viruses, vandalize the data, **infiltrate  systems**, damage  hardware or software, or in any way degrade or disrupt the use of the network.
- **Students**  and/or  employees  **using  School  equipment  or  property,  on-site or off-site**, must conform to the requirements of this policy.

<sup>I emphasized some of the more relevant phrases, but they are not to be taken out of context.</sup>

It surprises most students and parents (some employees as well) that they agreed to this.  Even if they didn't provide a signature on the acceptable use policy, because we have (electronically) *an affirmation of consent and acknowledgement* when the user first signs on to the computer (in other words, they have to read all of that and click "I agree"), they are ultimately bound by the rules.

The rules are so written that no matter where you are or what you intent is, trying to circumvent security will put you in a position of deep consequence.    Depending on how strict (or vindictive) your school administrators are, it could be considered a criminal activity.  Depending on your state, provincial or even national government, doing this could be a crime.

My (non-legal, but you'd be hard pressed to find a lawyer who disagrees) adivse to you is ***Don't Do It!***.  If you really need social network, ask your parents or save up for a cheap laptop or tablet.  This is not the fight you want to have because you simply can't win and the consequences are too great.